# ms-access merge two records with similar Id

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to merge two records with similar **Id** and similar **Date** in an attendance app
i have this table which **code=1** means **start** and **code=2** means **finish**

```
Id        Date           Time                 Code
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         2016.05.01     12:15                 1
1         2016.05.01     18:15                 2
2         2016.05.02     14:35                 1
2         2016.05.02     20:35                 2
x         xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxx                 x
```

and i want to show my table in this way

```
Id        Date           Time_Start          Time_Finish
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         2016.05.01     12:15               18:15
2         2016.05.02     14:35               20:35
x         xxxxxxxxxx     xxxxx               xxxxx
```

i found this query

```
SELECT Id,Date,
 MAX(CASE  WHEN code =1 THEN Time END) AS  Time_Start,
 MAX(CASE WHEN code =2 THEN Time END) AS  Time_Finish
FROM tbl_attendance
GROUP BY Id,  Date
```

but actually ms-access does not support **CASE WHEN** 
also i could not use **IIF** instead of that in a correct structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be (taken a logical approach ignoring *Code*):

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    [Date],
    Min(CDate([Time])) AS Time_Start,
    Max(CDate([Time])) AS Time_Finish
FROM 
    tbl_attendance
GROUP BY 
    Id,  
    [Date]
```

To keep output as text:

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    [Date],
    Format(Min(CDate([Time])), "hh:nn") AS Time_Start,
    Format(Max(CDate([Time])), "hh:nn") AS Time_Finish
FROM 
    tbl_attendance
GROUP BY 
    Id,  
    [Date]
```

or alternatively:

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    [Date],
    Sum(CDate(IIf([Code] = 1, [Time], "0"))) AS Time_Start,
    Sum(CDate(IIf([Code] = 2, [Time], "0"))) AS Time_Finish
FROM 
    tbl_attendance
GROUP BY 
    Id,  
    [Date]
```

Comment: It's not possible to work with Time because the type is character

Comment: tanx but i still need to work with code for many other reasons.is there any way?

Comment: Can't see what should hold you back from "work with code", but you can format the time values to text if that is what you mean. See edit.

Comment: some worker will stay at work for more than one day so in a day, a worker may only have start Time or Finish Time. if he just finished in a day , it would be appear as Start Time because there is no other value

Comment: Oh, that your sample data didn't indicate.

Comment: You may be able to use _Sum_ to obtain the output. See edit.